# Magento add wishlist block to cart.phtml

Tags: magento, cart

I have a simple question that I can't seem to find an answer for.  All I'm trying to do is make the wishlist viewable when a customer goes to the shopping cart page. That's all. So when a customer clicks on the cart button it takes them to their shopping cart page and they can see their items in their cart plus all the items on their wishlist.  There doesn't seem to be any tutorials for this anywhere.  I'm sure the answer is fairly simple but I'm relatively new to Magento.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

local.xml

```
    <checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="wishlist/customer_sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="wishlist" after="cart_sidebar" template="wishlist/sidebar.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

cart.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('wishlist'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should work: In your theme's `local.xml`, inside the `<layout></layout>` node, it should work to use this:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="wishlist/customer_sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="wishlist" after="cart_sidebar" template="wishlist/sidebar.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

If you look at `base/default/layout/checkout.xml`, you can see that the coupon- and shipping-block are in the same position. After that, go to your theme's checkout/cart.phtml and add a line:

```
<?php
echo $this->getChildHtml('wishlist_sidebar');
?>
```

...anywhere in this file.

Maybe you want to give the block another name other than `wishlist_sidebar` or use another template file than `wishlist/sidebar.phtml`. Just change the XML accordingly.

Comment: Thank you I will try this and let you know the outcome.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I'm utilizing the wishlist.view.phtml instead of sidebar.  I modified the xml and cart.phtml accordingly with no luck.

Comment: If you work with developer mode enabled, you should see some error. If not on the screen, then in system.log; can you post these? Also, is your wishlist.view.phtml a default file? If not, please post the contents, then I can help

Comment: Ok I got it to work.

This was added to my local XML

Comment: Great :) You can post & accept an answer to your own question, so this question gets marked as "solved"